# A matrix problem 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a $3 \times 3$-matrix $A$ such that $A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
        13 & 9 & -9 \\
        0 & 4 & 0 \\
        12 & 12 & -8 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
and $a_{11}, a_{22}>0$

I noticed that $A^2-4I$ is somewhat simpler form but don't know how to find $A$. How can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions for $A$, e.g., 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
11 & 9 & -9 \cr
0 & 2 & 0 \cr
12 & 12 & -10
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 3 & -3 \cr
0 & 2 & 0 \cr
4 & 4 & -2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Even for arbitrary given coefficients $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ there is such a matrix $A$.
Say, for $a_{11}=a_{22}=1$ we have
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 9/2 & 0 \cr
8/3 & 1 & -2 \cr
8/3 & 9/2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The best things is, of course, to diagonalize, but here in this case
it is easy to solve the $9$ equations in the $9$ variables 
directly, given by the matrix equation $A^2=B$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  First diagonalise $A^2=P^{-1}DP$. Then consider $P^{-1}\sqrt D P$.